# PictureBox not redrawing after RotateFlipType but it works with a breakpoint

Tags: c#, breakpoints, picturebox, redraw

I have simplified this to make sure nothing else is going on. So I have a windows form application, 1 form, 1 button and 1 picturebox. The following is the only code I have added.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

When I have a breakpoint in this routine the picture is shown as rotated. If Idon't have a breakpoint the picture does not rotate.

Any ideas? The code can't get more simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call either `Refresh()` or `Invalidate()` function on `PictureBox` control to Update it after Rotating.

From MSDN:Invalidate

> Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control
>   to be redrawn.

Try : using **Invalidate()**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. The explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
 pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
 pictureBox1.Refresh();
 Application.DoEvents();
```

Comment: Thank you. It does the job :)